# Storing email,phone,fax and url in same table

Tags: mysql

Is it ok to store email,phone,fax and url in same table?
I want user to be able to add multiple email,phone,fax or website url on their profile.

Here's my current table

**Contacts**

id

user_id

val (eg. test@mail.com,09222229291, http://facebook.com/test,432-2233)

contact_id

**ContactTypes**

id

name (eg. mobile,tel,email,url,fax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE client
(
  client_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  client_name VARCHAR(100)
  .. other
  .. client
  ., fields
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE contact
(
  contact_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  client_id INT,
  contact_type VARCHAR(3),  -- (e.g. 'URL', 'PH', 'FAX'  &c.)
  contact_value VARCHAR(256),
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_contact_client) REFERENCES client (client_id)
);
```

A few things to note:

- No need for a `contact_type` table unless there are many (rule of thumb, more than ~7 and/or if your codes are not intuitive).
- Of course, you can add a `contact_type` child table to `contact` if you wish, in the same manner as `contact` is a child to `client`. Whether you decide you want to do this will depend on your use case and the number of `contact_type`s.
- It's a pity that MySQL doesn't have `CHECK` constraints, which would be ideal for a small number of contact types. Whatever you do, don't use an `ENUM` type, they are [evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)
- If restricting/controlling contact_type is important to you, use a lookup table. This is not "clutter" - many small reference  tables are a "good thing" and MySQL can cope with 1000's of tables. Take a look at the first reference in my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/142841/34007) - avoid the OTLT (One True Lookup Table) trap. Also, see [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/declarative-sql-using-check()--default-/) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/using-enum-vs-check-constraint-vs-lookup-tables/6704/2) for further discussion ( [Joe Celko](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Celko) is a big hitter in the world of SQL).

Comment: You could give me a +1 so, as helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to normalize your data, you will need separate tables for phone/fax numbers, addresses, and websites.  When normalizing data repeating groups require a child table.

Comment: I think the point of the question was about not using  .csv datatypes - the line "val (eg. test@mail.com,09222229291, http://facebook.com/test,432-2233)" meant email **OR** URL **OR**...... In fact, the OP wanted to know about storing **multiple**  emails, URLs, phones &c. per user.

Comment: There is very little advantage in 'normalizing' urls, emails, addresses.  Phone numbers are 1:many, so a table of them (home, work, fax, cell, second cell, girl friend, probation officer, etc) can be useful because of open-endedness.

Comment: @RickJames If there is only one URL, eMail, or address, then I would leave them in the main table. However, I am increasing seeing multiples of each on systems.

Comment: @BillThor - I agree with what you are saying, but I think the word "normalize" is not appropriate.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) talks about "minimizing data redundancy"; moving repeating groups out needs a 1:N mapping, which does not provide for reduced redundancy.